# After Adding Search Filter Recycler View gives Wrong Position

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview

In My code I am getting total 214 countries from api which I have displayed on Recycler View. When I click on the country flag I am getting a Toast with country position (Getting correct position without searching). But when I search any country from search option and then I click on the flag I am getting wrong position **[When the country is searched the Searched country comes on the top and it takes that position]**. I don't know why it is so and what mistake I am doing in code??

For Example, Let assume 4 countries. At pos 0 - India, pos 1 - Germany, pos 2 - Pakistan, pos 3 - France.
Now this four countries has been displayed on Recycler View then `onClick` of India it displays position 0 and when I click on Germany it will display position 1 (without searching). **But when I search France from the list and I click on France after searching it should display position 3 but it is not**.

My `CustomAdapter.kt` for `RecyclerView` .

```
class CustomAdapter(public val context: Context, private val countriesResponse: CountriesResponse) :
RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.MyViewHolder>(), Filterable {

var country : ArrayList<CountriesResponseItem>
var list_country: ArrayList<CountriesResponseItem>
internal var mFilter: NewFilter

override fun getFilter(): Filter {
    return mFilter
}

init {
    list_country = getCountries()
    country = ArrayList()
    country.addAll(list_country)
    mFilter = NewFilter(this@CustomAdapter)
}

fun getCountries(): ArrayList<CountriesResponseItem> {
    val list_country = arrayListOf<CountriesResponseItem>()
    for (list1 in countriesResponse)
        list_country.add(list1)
    return list_country
}


class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView), View.OnClickListener {

    var image: ImageView
    var cv_tv_country_name: TextView

    init {
        image = itemView.cv_iv_country_flag
        cv_tv_country_name = itemView.cv_tv_country_name
        image.setOnClickListener(this)
    }

    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        val intent =
            Intent(v?.context, CountryWiseDataActivity::class.java).putExtra("position", position)
        v?.context?.startActivity(intent)

        //Toast when clicked on Item 
        Toast.makeText(v?.context,"Item Clicked at " + getPosition(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}


val VIEW_TYPE = 1

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
    var itemView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.flag_list, parent, false)
    return MyViewHolder(itemView)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return country.size
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
    Glide.with(context).load(country[position].countryInfo.flag).into(holder.image)
    holder.cv_tv_country_name.text = country[position].country
}

inner class NewFilter(var customAdapter: CustomAdapter) : Filter() { <-- Search Filter
    override fun performFiltering(constraint: CharSequence?): FilterResults {
        country.clear()
        val results = FilterResults()
        if (constraint!!.isEmpty()) {
            country.addAll(list_country)
        } else {
            val filterPattern = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim() { it <= ' ' }
            for (list_country1 in 0..list_country.size) {
                if (list_country[list_country1].country.toLowerCase()
                        .contains(filterPattern)
                ) {
                    country.add(list_country[list_country1])
                }
            }
        }
        results.values = country
        results.count = country.size
        return results
    }

    override fun publishResults(constraint: CharSequence?, results: FilterResults?) {
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

}
    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        return position.toLong()
   }
}
```

In Activity I have done as below for search filter

```
search_countries.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {

        }

        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {

        }

        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
            countryAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString())
        }

    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should properly learn the recycler view core concept first. Here Recyclerview is not creating 214 view holders.

If the view is displaying list positions 0 through 3, the RecyclerView creates and binds those view holders, and might also create and bind the view holder for position 4. That way, if the user scrolls the list, the next element is ready to display.

So the main concept here is recycling previous views. After searching for any item it again reorganizes its items & gives you its current position. That's why you are getting a random position.

To learn [visit here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview)